# TokensRegex pattern with negation of a user-defined "macro"

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am constructing a TokensRegex expression which is meant to capture text in the form of "N Maple St" of "W Mullholland Drive". The current expression is this:

```
{
ruleType: "tokens",
pattern: (/[A-Z]/ ([{ner:PERSON}|{tag:NNP}])+),
result: Concat($$0.text, "=", "STREET")
}
```

However, this also captures text  like "A Honda Accord". I have defined a macro for all the different car brands, similar to:

```
$VEHICLES = "/[Hh]onda|[Tt]oyota/"
```

I want to incorporate the negation of the $VEHICLES macro into the TokensRegex expression, i.e. the pattern section above checks to see if the text captured by the {ner:PERSON} or {tag:NNP} tokens matches the $VEHICLES macro, and if it does, it is NOT a valid match.

Visually,

```
{
ruleType: "tokens",
pattern: (/[A-Z]/ ((([{ner:PERSON}|{tag:NNP}])&(!$VEHICLES))+),
// Matches the letter and the tokens and NOT anything in the macro.
// This pattern causes a ParseException when running CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFile
// in my pipeline code.
result: Concat($$0.text, "=", "STREET")
}
```

Is there support for this functionality in TokensRegex?